# When I want to express accessing a website, should I say “go on this website”?

Tags: word-usage

I am learning this [machine learning course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuyk1nLMhRm6WkyV2sFP81ENNnsnydcm_).

This lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=144)

> you can go on menti.com

When I want to express accessing a website, should I say “go on this website”?

It seems to be a little bit strange using "go on".

Comment: Check the comments and answers of this: [Go to a website or go at a website](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341711/go-to-a-website-or-go-at-a-website)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Go
>
> verb 1.3 (go to) Attend or visit for a particular purpose: we went to the cinema
>
> noun, informal 1 chiefly British An attempt or trial at something: have a go at answering the questions yourself
>
> noun, informal 2 British A person’s turn to use or do something: I had a go on Nigel’s racing bike
>
> [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/go)

You can consider a website to the place, so one might direct people to go to the website.